# When using Selenium WebDriver how do know what browser type i am using?

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Programming Language of choice is Java.
I have written a method in java, to which, i am passing the WebDriver as an argument...

```
public boolean myMethod(WebDriver webDriver, String option)
```

This method behaves differently if the browser type is Firefox or HtmlUnitDriver. Now withing this method how do i determine what is the browser type that i have instantiated for WebDriver?

One option that i have is to the method myMethod i should pass the browser type as well. Like...

```
public boolean myMethod(WebDriver webDriver, String option, String browser)
```

and during call
    Myclass.myMethod(webDriver, "One", "HT

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Java ‘instanceof’ operator to decide the driver type.

```
Ex:
if(webDriver instanceof HtmlUnitDriver) {
    System.out.println("HTML DRIVER");
}else if(webDriver instanceof FirefoxDriver) {
    System.out.println("FF DRIVER");
}
```